# Inverse of a positive definite matrix generated by Wishart in Julia

Tags: julia, distribution

I have created a positive definite matrix from Wishart in Julia using the Distribution package. I want to use this to generate random multivariate normal with the specified precision. Hence I use the canonical form of MvNormal, which is MvNormalCanon.

However I get a bit confused as the randomly generated matrix from Wishart although positive definite, its inverse is not. So sometimes it causes trouble generating from multivariate normal using that precision.

For example:

```
using Distributions
X=rand(Wishart(10, eye(10)))
isposdef(X) // true
isposdef(inv(X)) // false
```

I also use the MvNormalCanon for generating random vectors as below:

```
rand(MvNormalCanon(X*μ, X))
```

where μ is my mean vector. But the above creates a `Base.LinAlg.PosDefException(1)`. 
Should the inverse also be positive definite, and if yes why does Julia act like this?

P.S.It might be adding a tiny bit to the scale matrix in Wishart might resolve the problem.

Comment: `isposdef` first checks that the input matrix is Hermitian. In this case, this check fails because of rounding errors from taking the inverse. One solution would be to use the `Symmetric` wrapper: `X = Symmetric(rand(Wishart(10, eye(10)))); iX = inv(X); isposdef(iX)`